# Damping of motion of a conductor

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current

The motion of a conductor is damped when allowed to oscillate between magnetic pole pieces. Two questions:-

1. How is the damping force produced by eddy current?
2. Why eddy current is undesirable in most cases?

Comment: Check this out if it helps...http://www.researchgate.net/publication/227175659_Modeling_and_experiments_on_eddy_current_damping_caused_by_a_permanent_magnet_in_a_conductive_tube

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. How is the damping force produced by eddy current?

As in the picture given below, the moving conductor experiences a change in magnetic flux as it passes through the magnet. This change in magnetic flux, in turn, by Lenz's Law produces an induced EMF on the conductor. Hence an eddy current flows in    clockwise\anticlockwise direction thereby inducing opposite magnetic poles on the sides of the conductor such that there is attraction between the conductor and the magnet. This causes a damping force and hinders the movement of the conductor.

[image: eddy current damping]

> 2. Why eddy current is undesirable in most cases?

The eddy current is undesirable because it is responsible for overheating in electrical machines. It also causes energy or power losses as certain portion of the kinetic energy is manifested in overcoming the damping force due to eddy current.